# How to convert UTC to Browser Locale Using Angular2

Tags: angular, locale

Trying to convert server UTC datetime to browser locale datetime using angular2.

Comment: your server side technology and language?

Comment: Server side is Java responding with JSON payload

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
let dateUTC = '2012-11-29 17:00:34 UTC';
let dateLocale = new Date(dateUTC);

console.log(dateLocale);
```